# Procrustes Problem with Maximization (Instead of Minimization)

Tags: optimization, procrustes-problem

The classical [(orthogonal) Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) is to solve the optimization problem
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min&\|\Omega{A}-B\|_F\\
\text{s.t.}&\Omega^\mathrm{T}\Omega=I
\end{array}
$$
The solution to this problem is well-known. I'm curious about the solution to
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max&\|\Omega{A}-B\|_F\\
\text{s.t.}&\Omega^\mathrm{T}\Omega=I
\end{array}
$$
(max instead of min). Given $A$ and $B$, we could solve the minimization problem to get $\Omega_0$. My intuition tells me that the optimal solution to the maximization problem is then $-\Omega_0$. We rotate $A$ to be as close to $B$ as possible, then flip it "180 degrees" in the opposite direction. Is there a simple proof or counterexample to this claim?

Answer (score 0):

I think that my suggested solution is correct. Following the Wikipedia article, notice that
$$
\|\Omega{A}-B\|_F^2=\langle\Omega{A}-B,\Omega{A}-B\rangle=\|A\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2-2\langle\Omega{A},B\rangle
$$
and thus maximizing $\|\Omega{A}-B\|_F^2$ is equivalent to minimizing $\langle\Omega{A},B\rangle$. But, using the SVD $AB^\mathrm{T}=U\Sigma{V^\mathrm{T}}$,
$$
\langle\Omega{A},B\rangle=\langle\Omega,AB^\mathrm{T}\rangle=\langle\Omega,U\Sigma{V^\mathrm{T}}\rangle=\langle{U^\mathrm{T}}\Omega{V},\Sigma\rangle.
$$
The matrix ${U^\mathrm{T}}\Omega{V}$ is orthogonal as a product of orthogonal matrices, and thus the expression is minimized when ${U^\mathrm{T}}\Omega{V}=-I$ (since $\Sigma$ is diagonal with non-negative entries). Hence, the solution is $\Omega^*=-UV^\mathrm{T}$, the negative of the solution to the minimization problem.

Comment: Take the SVD of $BA^T\,$ **_not_** $\,AB^T$